# Программа на Pascal

Tags: pascal

срочно, помогите пожалуйста, нужно написать программу на паскаль, которая по данной стороне равностороннего треугольника расчитывает площадь, высоту, радиус вписанной и выписанной окружности.

Comment: Для начала выведите формулы, они несложные, и их нетрудно найти, потом реализуйте вычисление на паскале. Если не все получится - задавайте конкретные вопросы

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Вот программа, надеюсь, что она поможет.

(Примечание: :4:4 в конце выражений делается для того, чтобы ограничить вывод вещественной переменной до 4 десятичных цифр после запятой. Без этого у нас будет что-то типа 0.5116434E-0001):

```pascal
uses Math;
var a: real;

begin
  writeln('Введите сторону равностороннего треугольника: ');
  readln(a);
  writeln('Площадь: ', Sqrt(3) * a*a / 4:4:4);
  writeln('Высота: ', Sqrt(3) * a / 2:4:4);
  writeln('Радиус вписанной окружности: ', a / (2 * Sqrt(3)):4:4);
  writeln('Радиус описанной окружности: ', a / Sqrt(3):4:4);
end.
```